# Flutter Android Notification not being Shown

Tags: android, flutter, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-push-notification

I'm developing an app in Flutter and using Firebase to send Push Notifications, the phone is receiving them but the issue is that I wan't to display a little retancle with some text inside such as WhatsApp does when you receive a new message, but mines just go for the top of the notifications bar and doesn't show anything. Does anyone know how to proceed or how is called the component that I need to implement?

Expected result:

[image]

Thank you!!

Comment: Same here. I received notification but it doesn't show. Is there any solutions?